# get filename , file path , get the line when the search string is found and extract only a part followed by search string of that line

Tags: python, bash, split, grep

may be I will directly explain with example : I am writing my code in python , for grep part also using bash commands.

I have few files , where I need to grep for some pattern , let's say "INFO"
All those files can be present two different dir structure : tyep1, type2

1. /home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/121/patching/a.log (type1)
2. /home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/SUB_JOB1/121/DB:1/patching/b.log (type2)
3. /home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/SUB_JOB1/142/DB:2/patching/c.log (type2)

contents of file :

```
a.log :
[Thu Jan 20 21:05:00 UTC 2022]: database1: INFO: Subject1: This is subject 1.

b.log :
[Thu Jan 22 18:01:00 UTC 2022]: database1: INFO: Subject2: This is subject 2.

c.log :
[Thu Jan 22 18:01:00 UTC 2022]: database1: ERR: Subject3: This is subject 3.
```

So I need to know which are all the files does "INFO" string is present. if present I need to get following :

filename : a.log / b.log

filepath : /home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/121/patching or /home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/SUB_JOB1/121/DB:1/patching

immediate string after search string : Subject1 / Subject2

So I tried using grep command with -r to know what are all the files I can find "INFO"

```
$ grep -r /home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB
/home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/121/patching/a.log:[Thu Jan 20 21:05:00 UTC 2022]: database1: INFO: Subject1: This is subject 1.
/home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/SUB_JOB1/121/DB:1/patching/b.log:[Thu Jan 22 18:01:00 UTC 2022]: database1: INFO: Subject2: This is subject 2.
$
```

So I will store above grep python variable and need to extract above things from this output.

I tried initially splitting grep o/p with "\n" , so I will get two separate rows

```
/home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/121/patching/a.log:[Thu Jan 20 21:05:00 UTC 2022]: database1: INFO: Subject1: This is subject 1.

/home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/SUB_JOB1/121/DB:1/patching/b.log:[Thu Jan 22 18:01:00 UTC 2022]: database1: INFO: Subject2: This is subject 2.
```

and by taking each row , I can split with ":"
First row: I am able to split properly as ":" is at correct places.

```
file_with_path : /home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/121/patching/a.log(I can get file name separate with os.path.basename(file_with_path))
immediate str after search word : "Subject1"
```

**Second row : This is where I need help , As in the path we have this "DB:1" which has ":" which will break my proper split. If I split I will get as below**

```
file_with_path : /home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/SUB_JOB1/121/DB (not correct)
actually should be /home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB/SUB_JOB1/121/DB:1/patching/b.log
```

I am unable to apply split here as it doesn't work properly for both the cases.

Can you please help me with this? any command that can do this work in bash or python would be very helpful.
Thank you In Advance. Also let me know if some info is needed from me.

giving code below:

```
# main dir 
        patch_log_home = '/home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB'
        cmd = "grep -r 'INFO' {0}"
        patch_bug_inc = self._core.exec_os_cmd(cmd.format(patch_log_home))

        # if no occurrance reported continue
        if len(patch_bug_inc) == 0:
            return

        if patch_bug_inc:
            patch_bug_inc = patch_bug_inc.split("\n");

        for inc in patch_bug_inc:
             print("_________________________________________________")

             inc = inc.split(":")

             # to get subject part
             patch_bug_str_index = [i for i, s in enumerate(inc) if 'INFO' in s][0]
             inc_name = inc[patch_bug_str_index+1]

             # file name 
             log_file_name = os.path.basename(inc[0])

             # get file path
             log_path = os.path.split(inc[0])
             print("log_path :", log_path)
             full_path = log_path[0]
             print("FULL PATH: ", full_path)
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to use *grep* for this? It would be much easier (and more portable) if you did it all in Python

Comment: there is no particular reason about this. if in bash it is just simple grep which would be faster. So. Can you give me the possibility in python as well , So that I will have better scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could achieve this without calling out to *grep* which, as I said in my comment, may not be portable:

```
import os
import sys

for root, _, files in os.walk('/home/user1/logs/MAIN_JOB'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.log'):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            try:
                with open(path) as infile:
                    for line in infile:
                        if 'INFO:' in line:
                            print(path)
                            break
            except Exception:
                print(f"Unable to process {path}", file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Thanks alot Olvin Roght for the solution, It helped me to get what exactly I want :) . 
But on knowledge purpose , I am just curious is it not even possible to do with grep or any other bash commands?

Comment: Yes you can call out to grep but there's a significant overhead in doing so. Native Python is likely to be much faster. Also, AFAIK, there's no grep on Windows. Of course, if you don't want to use Python at all then judicious use of *find* and *grep* will work on Unix type systems. For example: find . -type f -name \\*.log -exec grep -l "INFO:" {} \; 2>/dev/null